# attempt to call method 'draw_self' (a nil value) error - when trying to call function of a table within an array

Tags: arrays, lua, love2d

I just started learning Lua and LOVE2D, I'm trying to make text input boxes, I've got 4 instances within an array and I'm trying to call their draw function within the **love.draw()**

```
TextBox = {
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    width = 256,
    height = 64,
    text = '',
    active = false,
    colors = {
        background = { 186, 163, 182, 220 },
        text = { 20, 20, 20, 255 },
        border = { 48, 44, 50, 230 },
        activeborder = { 236, 234, 115, 240 }
    }
}

function TextBox:init(o, x, y)
    local o = {}
    o.parent = self
    o.x = x
    o.y = y
    return o
end

function TextBox:draw_self()
    -- Draw the box
    love.graphics.setColor(unpack(TextBox.colors.background))
    love.graphics.rectangle('fill',
        textBoxArray[i].x, textBoxArray[i].y,
        TextBox.width, TextBox.height)
    ...
end
```

main.lua :

```
function love.load()    
    ...

    textBoxArray = {}
    for i=1,4 do
        ... -- Declaring xx and yy here
        textBoxArray[i] = TextBox:init(nil, 40+xx, 40+yy)
    end
end

function love.draw()
    for i=1,4 do
        textBoxArray[i]:draw_self()
    end    
end
```

I get an error when I try to call **:draw_self()**, **:init()** works just fine and I couldn't figure out what the issue might be. What's the proper way to call a method when the instance is within an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the proper way to call a method when the instance is within an array?

`textBoxArray[i]:draw_self()` is the correct way to call a "method" if `textBoxArray[i]` has been set up properly: `obj:method(...)` is (roughly) just syntactic sugar for `obj.method(obj, ...)`. That is, indexing `obj` with the string `"method"` must return a method which takes `obj` as the first parameter.

This isn't the case though; your constructor doesn't set a metatable. Let's take a look:

```lua
function TextBox:init(o, x, y)
    local o = {}
    o.parent = self
    o.x = x
    o.y = y
    return o
end
```

After this, `o` has fields `x`, `y` and `parent`. Accessing any other field will yield `nil`. In particular, `textBoxArray[i].draw_self` will be `nil` for all `i`. You're thus trying to call a `nil` value, which  throws an error. `o.parent` doesn't have any special effect (assuming you're not using an OOP library). Instead, the [standard pattern](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.1.html) is to do `self.__index = self` followed by `setmetatable(o, self)`. (There are various ways to vary this pattern. For example you might want to separate the metatable and the class table, and you might not want to do an "unnecessary" `self.__index = self` in every constructor call. A nice property of this "standard pattern" is that it [makes inheritance easy](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.2.html) though.)

Side note: The unused `o` parameter doesn't make sense. If you want to allow passing an existing table, use `o = o or {}` rather than `local o = {}`. Otherwise, just remove the parameter.

Let's take a look at `draw_self` now:

```lua
function TextBox:draw_self()
    -- Draw the box
    love.graphics.setColor(unpack(TextBox.colors.background))
    love.graphics.rectangle('fill',
        textBoxArray[i].x, textBoxArray[i].y,
        TextBox.width, TextBox.height)
    ...
end
```

The "method" is called `draw_self`, yet you're operating on the global `TextBox` table except for the usage of `textBoxArray[i]`. Both of these should be completely replaced with usage of `self`. Currently you're using method syntactic sugar (`function TextBox:init(...)` is equivalent to `TextBox.init = function(self, ...)` - it adds an implicit `self` parameter) here despite not using `self` at all.

Your `love.load` is fine. Your `love.init` is also fine except for the `o` quirk; depending on how you refactor your constructor, you'll probably want to remove the unused `nil` value.